# SQL how to get specific columns from a stored procedure inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, which when I execute it, I got this result:

[image]

I want to get a specific columns using another stored procedure.

How can I do that?

**What I have thought**

Creating a new temporary table and fill the two columns in it. But the stored procedure returns more than 3 billion rows. So, it is not a good performance to create a temporary table for them.

**If it is the only solution please tell me**

**Second idea**

I can't change the stored procedure because I only have permission to execute it not to modify it. So, the solution has to be in the stored procedure that I will write not in the stored procedure that I execute and that I can't modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use the OPENROWSET to execute and get only the required Column.

```
SELECT ColumnName    --<-- The columns required.
FROM 
 OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI'
            ,'Server=ServerName\InstanceName;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=DatabaseName'
            ,'EXECUTE dbo.Proc_Name')
```

**UPDATE**

As it says in the error message this feature is turned off by default in sql server. you need to allow by executing the following system stored procedures..

```
EXECUTE sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXECUTE sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: I got this error `SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.
`

Comment: @user2226785 see my update I have updated the answer. Before I posted this answer I test on my system and it worked. you need to execute the above mentioned system stored procedures.

Comment: I got this error `SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. `  I used this in the query `'Server=localhost\sqlserver;`

Comment: `sqlserver` is this your Instance name ?? execute this `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` to get the server name and instance name.

Comment: In addition to that error, is this feature, which is disabled by default, should be enabled? I mean, what if the database admistrator refuse to open it for me? isn't there any other solutions? Please don't forget the error that I had :)

Comment: If you want to use this openrowset then it needs to be enabled but by default sql server has it disabled. I am not sure what risks it can poses to the server and how it can be protected if this option is enabled. Please consult BOL to learn more about this.

Comment: It works now, Thank you, I will accept your answer, Please just last thing, isn't there any other solutions?

Comment: The Other solution would be to CREATE A temp table same structure as the result set being returned from the procedure and then use syntax something like `INSERT INTO #TempTable EXECUTE dbo.Proc` and then select the columns from your temp table which isnt a very great option as you will be using Tempdb excessively and bring Unwanted_Column X 3 Billion data that is not required :S not impressing at all.

Comment: If I want with using `OPENROWSET` option. How could I process the results please? Now I get the two columns which are col1 and col2. but each column has 3 billion value. how can I make a loop on these columns inside my stored procedure?

Comment: Post another question with some sample data and your desired output from them two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Either way, I beleive if you execute a stored procedure, SQL Server will run the whole thing (all the rows and columns will have to get returned), unless it takes some params which trim it. Only then can you extract what you want from it. It doesn't really matter whether you use a temp table or openrowset at that point to get what you want from it.